# Is factorial of any number is Parallelizable?

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp

Can the calculation Factorial of any number is parallelizable? how ?

Comment: [Is this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34978236/parallelizing-factorial-calculation) helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, why not? Multiplication is associative. a * (b * (c * d)) == (((a * b) * c) * d) == (a * b) * (c * d). The implications for a divide-and-conquer parallelization scheme should be clear.

However, this would only have any tangible benefit for products of *many* numbers, and if you're talking about factorials, that means you're dealing with *huge* products, beyond the range of any computer's native integers, which means you're dealing with arbitrary-precision arithmetic... in which case you might have the opportunity to parallelize a *single multiplication* (Karatsuba multiplication is recursive, and the FFT in FFT-based multiplication is also very parallelizable), and if you can use up all of your resources that way, then there's no point in parallelizing at a higher layer.

For calculating reasonably-sized factorials, the fastest approach is probably the direct, single-threaded one, which has no overhead.